# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Prepare() throw exception in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets, websocket

i have c# server program which accepting clients smoothly and working correctly..
after a while it stops accepting clients giving me the below exception message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection is not open.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Prepare()
at myproject.mycsfile.functionname()
```

has anyone experienced such exception details before?
thanks in advance

Comment: Show your full code please. Are you sure your connection is open?

Comment: @SonerGönül i said: the connection stop opening after a while (about 12 hours)of smooth work..

Comment: Probably the connection was just broken/closed. It seems as if it was a connection to MySQL server, maybe it just should be re-established.

Comment: @Inspired , yes it have a mysql connection and also it talk to clients who request for some data from that Mysql DB

Comment: Do you open a new connection to MySQL for each client? for each request? If yes, you can run out of allowed connections. If no, you should be able to handle situations when an existing connection is unexpectedly closed. (In fact, you should handle it anyway.)

Comment: @SonerGönül i suspect the issue is not related with the code, since it working correctly for hours with multiple client.. i have some thought but not based on strong background,, that might the long open connection with mysql DB, or maximum number of client has reached.. but i am not sure

Comment: @Inspired, no its one connection opened.
do u mean that i have to check the connection status before trying any sql operations ?

Comment: Yes, you should check the connection status. And probably you should have also some decent retry policy (e.g. retry two times and then return an error to client). Network *is* unreliable.

Comment: @user4591 im having the same problem ; have you found the solution yet ; can you share with me pls ?